# Proof by induction and number sets (very simple question)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was working on the following question:

> Use the principal of mathematical induction to prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $n^3 +3n^2+2n$ is divisible by 6.

The book's answer is the following:

[image]

[image]

Given that I arrived at the same answer, I won't bother placing it here. My question is actually related to the number sets the author uses throughout the solution on the exercise.

**Questions:**

- Why does the author uses $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ for $(A+B)$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}^+$? Given that $A \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $B \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, shouldn't $(A+B) \in \mathbb{Z}^+$?
- Can I always use the same set for both $n$ and $k$ (in this case, state that $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ as well)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The author could have also written $(A + B) \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. You are correct that $A, B \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ implies $(A + B) \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ because the set of positive integers is closed under addition. However, since $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, it does not make a difference here.
- Yes. If you're trying to prove a property for all $n$ in some set, then the value you "suppose" it's true should belong to the set as well. From there, you should try to construct a subsequent value that belongs to that set. It wouldn't make sense to take $k$ in a set that $n$ is not in because you would have a false premise.

Comment: Thank you @Ekesh, that was very "straight to the point" (I'm not sure how to use that expression in English, I hope you understood). Have a great one!

Comment: Thank you! You too. That makes sense in this context :)